# accessing a web page, rather than a local file?

Tags: jquery, json, localhost, tumblr

I'm trying to embed vimeo videos posted on a tumblr page to my new website. To do this, I'm   reading the video source information from the json file of the tumblr page which can be accessed via http://vimeo.tumblr.com/api/read/json

and then trying to append it to my web page using jquery.
However, it seems like chrome interprets the //player.vimeo.com link to be a local directory and not the website! What should I do about this?

Here is essentially what I have right now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>
<div id="helloWorld"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Karen/jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vimeo.tumblr.com/api/read/json">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
      var link = tumblr_api_read.posts[i]["video-source"]
  $("div#helloWorld").append(link + "<br>");
}


 </script>

</head>
</html>
```

EDIT: sorry for any confusion, I was trying to solve a problem I was facing when the video-sources were wrapped in an iframe, and caused the browser to look for file://player.vimeo.com....

I was able to solve the problem by doing this

```
var link = tumblr_api_read.posts[i]["video-source"];
  if (link){
     link = link.replace("//player", "http://player")
     $("div#helloWorld").append(link + "<br>");
  }
```

Comment: What's not working? Could use cleaning up. But your code works. http://jsfiddle.net/psradich/6VuhJ/

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, I was actually using a different tumblr with iframes for the video sources but changed it for privacy reasons without knowing they were different.

Comment: ah. don't know that I can help much with out at least a similar source

Comment: I got it, i'll keep that in mind for any future questions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` is relative: it will point using the protocol that is appropriate for the task at hand: if you are testing this webpage locally, `//` is always going to point to `file://`. If you were doing this online, it would use either `http://` or `https://`, depending on the protocol of the resource you are accessing.

To fix this, just be explicit about the protocol you'd like to use, be it `http` or `https`.